# Is it possible to have two BLE beacons communicating with each other?

Tags: bluetooth, device, sensors, proximity

Working on a quick and fun project. I have 2 beacons at home: One attached to my dog collar and the other attached to my sneakers. Basically I want to get a notification at work on my phone whenever the dog gets close to the sneaker.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in general two beacons cannot communicate with each other. Reason being, both beacons are servers which can provide certain information. Mobile phones connect to them as a client and fetch information. 
Now, since both the beacons are server they cannot connect to each other. To connect to each other either of them should be client. Which is not there in case of beacons.